# Using Linq to GroupBy and Select

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I'm looking to do a GroupBy and a Select in Linq, but the following doesn't compile:

```
foreach (string fooName in fooList.GroupBy(f => f.Name).Select(f => f.Name))
{
    ...
}
```

Why am I unable to use `f => f.name` in my `Select` clause? More importantly, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GroupBy` returns a sequence of `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>`, so the lambda parameter in the `Select` method is of type `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>`, not `TSource`. Instead you can do this:

```
foreach (string fooName in fooList.GroupBy(f => f.Name).Select(grouping => grouping.Key))
{
    ...
}
```

But anyway, there is a simpler way to achieve the same result:

```
foreach (string fooName in fooList.Select(f => f.Name).Distinct())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`GroupBy` groups the values into key value pairs, so you probably want

```
 foreach (string fooName in fooList.GroupBy(f => f.Name).Select(f => f.Key))
 {
    ...
 }
```